# send data in utf-8 to database for android app

Tags: java, php, android

I want to send some text data with `utf-8` encoding to database.

I use this code

```
      if (JsonUtils.isNetworkAvailable(Activity_Feedback.this)) 
      {
          new MyTaskFeedBack().execute(Constant.FEEDBACK_URL+strName+"&email="+strEmail+"&message="+strMsg,"UTF-8");
      }
```

But it doesn't work . Please help me.

Comment: **1.** what doesn't work? **2.** you haven't stated what happens in your `MyTaskFeedBack` or posted its code (please update your question with the code).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code. It may help you,

```
if (JsonUtils.isNetworkAvailable(Activity_Feedback.this))
{
    String name = "";
    String email ="";
    String message = "";
    try {
        name = URLEncoder.encode(strName, "UTF-8");
        email = URLEncoder.encode(strEmail, "UTF-8");
        message = URLEncoder.encode(strMsg, "UTF-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    new MyTaskFeedBack().execute(Constant.FEEDBACK_URL+name+"&email="+email+"&message="+message);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Donot ENCODE the full Link, just encode the parameters that you are sending

if you want to encode the string the write the following code

```
 String encoded_name = "";
 String encoded_email = "";
 String encoded_message = "";
    try {

        encoded_name = URLEncoder.encode(name, "UTF-8");
        encoded_email = URLEncoder.encode(email, "UTF-8");
        encoded_message = URLEncoder.encode(strMsg, "UTF-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {

        Log.e("tag", "exception : "+e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
new MyTaskFeedBack().execute(Constant.FEEDBACK_URL+encoded_name+"&email="+encoded_email+"&message="+encoded_message);
```

Comment: Can you complete the code?
I tried but it did not work.

Comment: @JimCarrey check my updated answer.

Comment: im use it and work. im very happy.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
HttpGet request = new HttpGet(Constant.FEEDBACK_URL+strName+"&email="+strEmail+"&message="+strMsg,
                                "utf-8");
new MyTaskFeedBack().executeRequest(request);
```